# Run function when all div elements are set to display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In this code I want the paragraph text to change to murderer after all the div elements are display to none. In this problem the paragraph text changes to murderer only one of the div elements are display to none. I understand I can use the if statement and give the condition for display:none individually and then run the function but what if there are hundred div elements. This is just a fun experiment and I need an efficient way of doing this.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Learning jQuery</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
     #green {
      width:200px;
      height:200px;
      background-color:green;
      border-radius:50%;
      margin-top:50px;
     }
     .red {
      width:200px;
      height:200px;
      background-color:red;
      margin-top:50px;
     }
    </style> 
</head>

<body>
 <div id="green"></div>
 <div class="red"></div>
 <div class="red"></div>
 <h1 id="murder">Hello</h1>
 <script>
  $("murder").html("murderer!");
  $("div").click(function() {
   $(this).css("display", "none");
   if ($("div").css("display") == "none") {
    $("#murder").html("murderer!"); 
   }
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With jQuery's [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector:

```
if($("div:visible").length == 0) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: hahaha that is so awesome! Thank you so much. I will study this method you have shown me.

Answer (score 0):

Does this give you what you want? You could devise a more sophisticated/complex solution using events but that may be overkill for your requirements?

```
$("div").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();

    if ($("div:visible").length == 0) {
        $("#murder").html("murderer!"); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
    $("div").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        if (!$('div:visible').length) {
            $("#murder").html("murderer!"); 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

DEMO:

```js
        $("murder").html("murderer!");
        $("div").click(function () {
            $(this).css("display", "none").addClass("hidden");
            alert($("div.hidden").length);
            if ($("div.hidden").length == 3) {
                $("#murder").html("murderer!");
            }
        });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #green {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: green;
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin-top: 50px;
        }

        .red {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: red;
            margin-top: 50px;
        }
    </style>


    <div id="green"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <h1 id="murder">Hello</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) function:

```js
function isInvisible(e) {
  return e.style.display == "none";
}


$("div").click(function() {
  $(this).css("display", "none");
  if ($("div").toArray().every(isInvisible)) {
    $("#murder").html("murderer!"); 
  }
});
```

```css
#green {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:green;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin-top:10px;
}
.red {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="green"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
<h1 id="murder">Hello</h1>
```